# Some .CLS error

Tags: macros

http://www.mmnp-journal.org/author-information/latex-examples

I am helping a friend with LaTeX, but I am not so much familiar with .cls macros. The source was from the address above.

When I tried to compile the file, I get following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1295 \StandardLayout
```

It is the 1295th line in the .cls file and I am not sure whether it's an old package loaded or something else caused it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: No solution really, but try `\providecommand{\StandardLayout}{}` before `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Now it's saying ` twosideshift undefined.` Can't really see what's gone wrong.

Comment: Well, there's more bad in that class ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following things in `mmnp.cls`:

- Replace `\StandardLayout` (provided by old versions of `babel`) by its equivalent in newer versions:

  ```
  \frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
  ```
- Add a comment sign in front of the option `twosideshift=0mm` of the `geometry` package. It is an old option that does not exist anymore.
- Move the line `\RequirePackage[frenchb,english]{babel}` immediately before `\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}`. Move the line `\RequirePackage[sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib}` immediately before `\RequirePackage[frenchb,english]{babel}` such that this part now reads

  ```
  %Babel
  %\StandardLayout
  \RequirePackage[sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib}
  \RequirePackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
  \frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
  ```

  The purpose of this shuffling is to load `natbib` before `babel`, but `natbib` depends on definitions further up so it cannot be moved up too far.
- Regarding the `natbib` error I don't really know. Maybe it is because there is no adequate bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to publish a manuscript there, in MMNP, then ask them for an updated class file. Maybe, they have changed other things as well in the meantime.

The class file `mmnp.cls`, [downloaded](http://www.mmnp-journal.org/images/stories/doc/latex/mmnp.cls) at 2017-02-13, contains
the following version date and number:

```
\ProvidesClass{mmnp}[2011/12/16
^^JLaTeX document class for MMNP journals - version 1.0]
```

There is nothing special about `\StandardLayout` except that it is not defined.
The name is too generic to get a clue, which layout aspects are configured there, or where it had come from, if the class file had worked at some time in the ancient past.

The next quirk is an error message about `twosideshift`. It comes from package `geometry` that had removed the option in version 5. Since the option is not
really used, as the value 0mm indicates, it can be disabled.

Both issues can be fixed by the following code that must be put *before*
`\documentclass`:

```
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{keyval}
\define@key{Gm}{twosideshift}{%
  \ifdim#1=0pt %
    % Ignore zero shift value
  \else
    \PackageWarning{geometry}{Option `twosideshift` is gone since version 5}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\providecommand*{\StandardLayout}{}
```

The first part provides a default definition of option `twosideshift` that prints a warning, if the option is used with a value other than zero.

The last line is taken from Christian Hupfer's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353641/some-cls-error#comment869515_353641) and provides
an empty definition for `\StandardLayout`.

If I run `pdflatex` on the example file `MMNP-format.tex`, then the following
error remains (apart from two errors because of missing images):

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

(natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.
```

At least, this should be clarified by the publisher, which style for the bibliography and for citing should be used.